# Finding most consequitive 1s in a dataframe over variable number of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with millions of rows and thousands of (variable number of) columns. I need to find the maximum number of rows with 1s in each column. A sample input and output pair are shown below:

```
Input:
    scala> val df = Seq(
       (1, 1, 1, 0),
       (2, 0, 1, 1),
       (3, 0, 1, 1),
       (4, 1, 1, 1),
       (5, 1, 1, 0),
       (6, 0, 1, 1),
       (7, 0, 0, 1)
    ).toDF("Sl", "col1", "col2", "col3")

    scala> df.show
    +---+----+----+----+
    | Sl|col1|col2|col3|
    +---+----+----+----+
    |  1|   1|   1|   0|
    |  2|   0|   1|   1|
    |  3|   0|   1|   1|
    |  4|   1|   1|   1|
    |  5|   1|   1|   0|
    |  6|   0|   1|   1|
    |  7|   0|   0|   1|
    +---+----+----+----+

Output:
    (2, 6, 3)
```

Given the size of data I can think of solving the above problem (in Scala) using imperative approach working with one column at a time, but that is not very efficient. I would be grateful for any help in solving this in a more practical way.

Comment: `data.filter(row => isOnlyOnes(row)).count()` the implementation of `isOnlyOnes` is leave for the reader.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Your solution seems to suggest to find rows with all 1s (which is easy with a simple UDF). I am looking for maximum consecutive 1s in each column (independent of other columns). For eg, for `col3` the series is `0111011` so the answer is 3.

Comment: so why the output is 2,6,3 instead of 4 ? it is the only column with 3 consecutive 1.

Comment: `col1` is `1001100` with 2 `1`s, `col2` is `1111110` with 6 and `col3` is `0111011` with 3 consecutive `1`s. If there is a break with `0` it doesn't count.

Comment: Sorry your question was not clear and I read it a bit slopy, sorry. You can do this: `val onesCount = data.map(row => getConsecutiveOnes(row)).cache` Then `val max = onesCount.max()` and finally `val count = onesCount.filter(_ == max).count()`